# Computed Properties and @each

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I've been reading through the docs and API and I'm having a hard time finding an explanation for the following:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  collectionTotal: function() {
    var games = this.get('model');
    return games.length
  }.property('@each')
});
```

What is actually happening with the `.property('@each')`? I know I am getting the computed property back, I don't understand what `@each` is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**What is `@each`?**

`@each` observes individual properties on each item in an array.

For example, if I observe `users.@each.name`, I will receive an event if:

- the `users` property is replaced e.g. `this.set('users', ...)`
- an item is added or removed from `users`
- the `name` property changes on any of the items

You can observe multiple properties using this syntax: `users.@each.{name,email}`

You cannot nest them. This will not work: `users.@each.friends.@each.mood`

Read more in the official documentation:

- [Computed Properties and Aggregate Data with @each](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/object-model/computed-properties-and-aggregate-data/)
- [Ember.ArrayProxy Class](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayProxy.html#property__each)

**To answer your question**

`@each` by itself doesn't make sense. You can observe the `[]` property if you only need to watch for items being added or removed.

Typically you should observe the same properties that are used in the body of the function. In your example that would be `model` and `length`:

```
  collectionTotal: function() {
    var games = this.get('model');
    return games.get('length');
  }.property('model.length')
```

Or equivalently:

```
  collectionTotal: function() {
    return this.get('model.length');
  }.property('model.length')
```

Or equivalently:

```
  collectionTotal: Ember.computed.reads('model.length')
```

Comment: Thank you. Makes total sense now. Is this documented?

Comment: Sure, I added some links